# Negamax not working beyond depth 1

Tags: chess, minimax, negamax

I am making a chess engine in C++ and with this algorithm, I get expected play with max depth set to 1. Beyond that however, it ignores pieces that are in danger and seems to even willingly put itself in danger.

Here is my code:

```
int negamax(int depth, int alpha, int beta)
{
    int max = -INFINITY;

    MoveList legalMoves;
    MoveGeneration::generateCaptureMoves(&legalMoves);
    MoveGeneration::generateQuietMoves(&legalMoves);

    // No legal moves
    if(legalMoves.count == 0)
    {
        if(Position::isCheck())
        {
            // Checkmate
            if(Position::activeColor == WHITE)
                return VAL_VICTORY;
            else
                return -VAL_VICTORY;
        }
        else
        {
            // Stalemate
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Go through legal moves
    for(int i = 0; i < legalMoves.count; i++)
    {
        // Get move score
        Position::doMove(legalMoves[i]);

        int score;
        if(depth == 0)
            score = quiescence(MAX_QUIESCENCE_DEPTH, alpha, beta);
        else
            score = -negamax(depth - 1, alpha, beta);

        Position::undoMove();

        // Pruning
        if(Position::activeColor == WHITE && score > beta) break;
        if(Position::activeColor == BLACK && score < alpha) break;

        if(Position::activeColor == WHITE && score > alpha) alpha = score;
        if(Position::activeColor == BLACK && score < beta) beta = score;

        // Best so far?
        if(score > max)
        {
            max = score;

            if(depth == MAX_DEPTH)
                bestMove = legalMoves[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
score = -negamax(depth - 1, -beta, -alpha);
```